# What if Allah freed one of his slaves?

Tags: terminology

We are all slaves of Allah, but what if he decided to free someone very noble who asked to be freed? What would happen to that person, if he decided not to continue to serve Allah as his servant? What if he continued to serve Allah as a servant?

If Mohammad (PBUH) asked to be freed, would Allah accept his wish?

Also, is Iblis free? He does not fit the definition of noble, so its a different question than the first one.

This is an opinion based question, but please support your opinion with evidence from the Quran and Hadith. And I know that it is unlikely anyone will ever ask Allah to free them due to gratitude towards Allah.

Comment: Please define the context of "free" in your question.

Comment: In the same way a human frees his slaves. Now the slave is no longer obligated to perform tasks for his former master, but can continue if he wants to.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Afaik, in the Quran, Allah says humans and jinns were not created except that they should worship Him (51:56) ... hence, your question in a way asks of a scenario that would negate Allah's intention. And nothing can happen without Allah's Will.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to Ahmed's answer by saying ,that jannah is metaphorically where humans are free to do what they want .

**So to bring this closer to your question** , you can think of us as slaves paying our price in dunya (This was a tradition in ancient times where a slave could agree with his master to buy himself , to pay "his" price) so that we can be free in the akhira , in jannah you won't be obliged to do anything and so , this brings us closer to your target state of the human , don't forget also that life is just for a small time while jannah is for eternity . A bargain ,don't you think !

**However** , that can't happen while we are still in dunya as our obligations are never lifted.

**As for Iblis** , define your concept of freedom here , if Iblis is free then also every human is free , I think your idea of freedom is doing whatever you want *without* being punished , but we all know he is going to be punished , so in that sense , no , he isn't freer than the average human.

Comment: Consider also ayat 93 from Surat-um-Maryam: “Not one of the beings in the heavens or on the earth but must come to Ar‘Rahmaan AS A SLAVE.” The simple Truth is that none of us will ever be “free” from being slaves of Allah - not in this world, and not in the next. Even in Jannah, where we be excused from the obligations of regular worship rituals and service, we will still be Allah‘s slaves. The nature of our bond with Allah is abd/Rabb (slave/Lord). That is NEVER going to change. As long as Allah remains “Rabb-in-Naas” (Lord of Mankind) we will - ALL OF US - be Ibaadillah (Allah‘s slaves).

Comment: @IbraheemMuhammad , I actually DO fully agree with you on this , it is just that some people can't reconcile the two concepts of being slaves to Allah and being free of obligations of worship . The person who asked seems to confuse both concepts together , referring to the obligations as the relation of worship to Allah , so in that context my answer holds true , we should be free of our obligation of worship in Heaven and so we should be free from our slave status (also in that context) . But yeah , I totally agree with you that our relation to Allah is eternal and reconcilable with freewill